# draw a circle inside each rectangle

Tags: r

[image]

I want to draw a circle inside each rectangle but the circle is outside the rectangle

here is my code

```
plot.new()
plot.window(xlim = c(-1,9),ylim = c(-1,9),asp=1)

 rect(1,1:8,1+1,9)
 theta <- seq(0, 2 * pi, length = 73)[1:72]
x=cos(theta)
y=sin(theta)
polygon(x,y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your circle is too large to start with. The boxes are 1 unit wide, so the circle's radius should be 0.5, not 1. The centre of each circle should coincide with the centre of each box. This is the set of co-ordinates [1.5, 1.5], [1.5, 2.5], [1.5, 3.5] etc. The circle you are drawing has its center at [0, 0].

The following modifications should work for you, assuming I have understood your requirements:

```r
plot.new()
plot.window(xlim = c(-1,9),ylim = c(-1,9), asp = 1)

rect(1, 1:8, 2, 9)
theta <- seq(0, 2 * pi, length = 73)[1:72]
x <- cos(theta)/2
y <- sin(theta)/2
sapply(1:8, function(a) polygon(x + 1.5, y + a + 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's really helpful!